# How can make RecyclerView item in front of some item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i know i can use GridLayoutManager But I need make it by RecyclerView.LayoutManager

[This i need To make by use RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I7iA.png)

[This is normal Of Recycler View Item In Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d94z7.png)

Comment: Use Grid layoutmanager and span count 3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make recycler with columns using RecyclerView.LayoutManager. You can create recycler into recycler, placing three items in recycler and this is will be your one item, or just put three items into one layout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can't set that layout with layoutManager but you can arrange the item positions in the Array list so it appears that way as described .

your step 1. would be to set the layout manager like this --

```
val rV = binding.recyclerView
val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
rV.layoutManager = layoutManager
layoutManager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```